# Changepic and keep original image size with adjust parameter

Tags: docx, opentbs

I have a template in which I'm attempting to change the source of a picture from Image 1, to Image 2 - yet I want Image 2 to keep the original size it was uploaded to the server in. (I want it in the position of Image 1, but its own dimensions.)

To do this, I figured I needed to use the `adjust` parameter - which I have attempted. The description for `adjust=100%` is "The picture is adjusted to be proportional to the original size." - which sounded like what I needed to do.

However, in my docx output, this seems to set the image size to be 100% of page width, rather than related to image size. (In the word image properties, it shows my image to be 208%, so I don't think it's related to my file!)

Is this a bug in opentbs, or have I misunderstood the docs? If so, how should I be doing it, or otherwise, can anyone thing of a work around? I attempted not using `adjust` at all, however that seems to have the same behaviour as `adjust=inside` - which I presume is the default.

With the normal thanks for a great tool!

Edit: The Error causing tag is below. I've found the problem reproducible when starting from nothing, and with just an image in the word doc. Word 2010, OpenTBS 1.8.

```
[onshow.logo;ope=changepic;tagpos=after;adjust=100%]
```

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://www.tinybutstrong.com/forum.php?thr=2761

Or are you actually seeing different behavior in your document using `adjust=100%' vs no adjust parameter on the same image?

Comment: Hello again Sarah! Was that the post you meant to link to? Just seems somewhat unrelated to your following sentence. Regardless, my tag comes after my image anyway - and I've just tried using the `tagpos` param to see if specifying that helped, but no difference. And yes, I see different behaviour with the two adjust behaviours you stated, although I believe that's because `adjust=inside` is the default behaviour? (As looking at that post you linked, that's how the library behaved before `adjust` was implemented.)

Comment: Yes, that's the post I intended. Just trying to zero in on the issue. You could try poking around in the tbs_plugin_opentbs.php. There is a function `TbsPicAdjust` which contains a silenced `getimagesize` function call - removing the `@` in front of the call may give you more info. I haven't used adjust personally, I just set the dimensions I want with a block (could be a workaround for you). Unfortunately, I can't find much info about `adjust` and I don't have a good setup right now to test it out...

Comment: Yeah, I had a look at that earlier. `getimagesize` returns correctly, and it looks like that individual function should be preserving the image size correctly, but I didn't follow it through to where that is written the Word XML. Maybe will follow that up tomorrow. How would you be setting the dimensions with a block, by inserting TBS tags in the dimension attribute of the the `drawing` tags? I may have to look into that, but would much rather I could still open my template with word if possible, it's quite a big one.

Comment: Did you checked that the image used in the template has a scale of 100 % ? (contextual menu on the image + item "Size and position" + tab "Size" + section "Scale")

Comment: Just to add, I tried a completely stripped down version of this with just an image and the tag in an empty word doc, and had the same effect - so I think it is entirely reproducible. I'll add my tag into the post above, this was made in Windows 2010, and OpenTBS 1.8.0.

Comment: @Skrol29 Got it figured out, posted as an answer below. Maybe something for the next version? Or maybe I've missed something, and it is particular to my set up, I'm not sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems was caused by the `TbsPicAdjust()` function expecting the image's dimensions to be provided in points, rather than pixels, as php's `getimagesize()` function was returning.

It was solved by replacing the two fixed coefficients in the `TbsPicGetDim_OpenXML_dml()` function with 9,525, rather 12,700 as they were originally coded. (Which would be an appropriate value, if the dimensions were in points, rather than pixels.)

After some research, from what I can see, `getimagesize()` always returns a size in pixels rather than points, so it looks to me like this could be a potential bug?

---

Additional Source for coefficient, combined with personal calculations: http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/f/15/p/396/933.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

It depends if you are using the new (.docx) or old (.doc) style of document. If you have the newer style, I don't know for sure that you can change the image size without putting the tag directly into the XML. The older (VML, I believe) style uses `<v:shape>` to describe a picture rather than `<pic:pic>`. With `v:shape`, you can just put together a CSS-style string that describes the size, etc. of your image. Something like:

```
$imgStyle = "position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:800;height:600"
```

Then you just have a tag next to your `changepic` tag; something like:

```
[imgStyle;att=v:shape#style]
```

The newer style does not use a style string like this to size and position images, the `pic:pic` element is full of nested tags describing the image so it is harder to get to the details (though you could certainly try). I ended up creating a subtemplate for my image switching because my template is in the new format with compatibility for the old format (so I have to maintain two image blocks). This allows me to maintain the XML directly for the image dimensions, but still be able to edit my main template in Word. I just use a tag in my main template that includes the subtemplate like:

```
[LineItem.template;block=w:r;file='img.xml']
```

Separating the manually controlled XML out allows me to edit the main template in Word without damaging the really custom parts. Using this technique though, you may have some trouble with onload/onshow tags in the subtemplate - everything I change in the subtemplate is controlled by a block.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Sarah. All my work is in `docx` format, so I'll need to look at the second solution, but actually, the image in question is in the header anyway, so perhaps instead I can remove that from my main template, and just include it on request. (So I can still edit my main template in word, and it's just my two headers I'll have to edit manually.)

If you don't mind, I won't accept just yet in case someone is able to offer a direct solution rather than a workaround, but I appreciate this, so I can get a working version out for now!!

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to give you an option to consider - this isn't really an answer to your question, just more info than I can fit into a comment.